# PySimpleGUI: How to not display empty field

Tags: hide, rows, pysimplegui

I've created the simple GUI as follow.
In the example only three rows are included, however the same principle can be applied to more of them.
I would like to fill all or same rows in the GUI and the save it, but most importantly when the saved files is loaded back only the filled rows (and not all) should be displayed.
I've tried in the way below but unsuccessfully..

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from datetime import datetime
import base64
from pathlib import Path
import webbrowser

sg.theme('DarkTeal9')      


layout_1 = [[sg.InputText("", key="-IT2-", font='Arial 9', size=(10,1)),
             sg.Combo(["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"],size=(20,1), key='-TEST2-', font='Arial 9'),
             sg.CalendarButton("", close_when_date_chosen=True,  target='-IN2-', font='Arial 9', no_titlebar=False, format='%d-%b-%Y'),
             sg.InputText("", key='-IN2-', size=(20,1), font='Arial 9')]]


layout_a = [[sg.Button("row 2")]]

layout_2 = [[sg.InputText("", key="-IT3-", font='Arial 9', size=(10,1)),
             sg.Combo(["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"],size=(20,1), key='-TEST3-', font='Arial 9'),
             sg.CalendarButton("", close_when_date_chosen=True,  target='-IN3-', font='Arial 9', no_titlebar=False, format='%d-%b-%Y'),
             sg.InputText("", key='-IN3-', size=(20,1), font='Arial 9')]]

layout_b =[[sg.Button("row 3")]]

layout_3 = [[sg.InputText("", key="-IT4-", font='Arial 9', size=(10,1), visible=True),
             sg.Combo(["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"],size=(20,1), key='-TEST4-', font='Arial 9'),
             sg.CalendarButton("", close_when_date_chosen=True,  target='-IN4-', font='Arial 9', no_titlebar=False, format='%d-%b-%Y'),
             sg.InputText("", key='-IN4-', size=(20,1), font='Arial 9', justification="c")]]

               
layout = [
          [sg.Column(layout_1, key='-LAY1-'), sg.Column(layout_a, visible=True, key="-LAYA-")],
          [sg.Column(layout_2, visible=False, key='-LAY2-'), sg.Column(layout_b, visible=False, key='-LAYB-')],
          [sg.Column(layout_3, visible=False, key='-LAY3-')],
          [sg.Button ("Save"), sg.Button ("Load"), sg.Button('Exit'),],
          ]
        

window = sg.Window("", layout)


while True:
    event, values = window.read()
        
    if event == 'Save':
        file_name = sg.popup_get_file("Save", save_as=True, no_window=True)
        window.SaveToDisk(file_name)
    if event == 'Load':
        file_name = sg.popup_get_file('Load', no_window=True)
        window.LoadFromDisk(file_name)
        if values["-IT2-"] != "":
            window[f'-LAY1-'].update(visible=True)
            window[f'-LAYA-'].update(visible=False)
        if values ["-IT3-"] != "":
            window[f'-LAY2-'].update(visible=True)
        if values["-IT4-"] != "":
            window[f'-LAY3-'].update(visible=True)
            
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
        window.close()
    if event == 'row 2':
        window[f'-LAY2-'].update(visible=True)
        window[f'-LAYA-'].update(visible=False)
        window[f'-LAYB-'].update(visible=True)
        layout = str(event)
    if event == 'row 3':
        window[f'-LAY3-'].update(visible=True)
        window[f'-LAYB-'].update(visible=False)
        layout = str(event)

window.close()
```

Comment: Hi Jason, sorry for the confusion. I will try to explain my thought as clear as possible. in the example I've filled just to rows and then I've saved the file.  However, when I reopen the saved file all the three rows are displayed and not only the two filled. I'm sorry, but I'm not able to attach pictures to show you what I mean

Comment: "How to not display empty field ?", just `window[element_key].update(visible=(value!=''))` if you can get the value of the filed.

Comment: The `values` is generated when you click the `Load` button, not the values after you call `LoadFromDisk`. Try to get the value by calling the method `get` of Input element. Remember also to handle when to set element invisible.

Comment: Sorry Jason, I would not to bother you, but my knowledge about python is not so advanced. Would be possible to have an example of get method?

Comment: In any case the [window[element_key].update(visible=(value!=''))] doesn't work. The empty rows are still displayed when I run [LoadFromDisk]

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```py
    if event == 'Load':
        file_name = sg.popup_get_file('Load', no_window=True)
        window.LoadFromDisk(file_name)
        v1, v2, v3 = window["-IT2-"].get(), window["-IT3-"].get(), window["-IT4-"].get()
        if v1:
            window[f'-LAY1-'].update(visible=True)
            window[f'-LAYA-'].update(visible=False)
        if v2:
            window[f'-LAY2-'].update(visible=True)
        if v3:
            window[f'-LAY3-'].update(visible=True)
```

Comment: Hi Jason, I can't thank you enough. Provided code works very well, according to my hope and expectations. Thanks again